# acceder a un indice concreto dentro de un array json ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs, jsonobject, jsonarray

estoy intentando seleccionar una posición concreta dentro de un array que está en un objeto Json. Es una llamada a una api que me devuelve lo siguiente:

{

"nombre":"Nombre1",

"apellido":"Apellido1",

"edad": "18",

"direccion": [

{

"id": 1,

"calle": 1

},

{

"id": 2,

"calle":2

}]

}

Este seria el ejemplo entonces yo estoy haciendo lo siguiente para renderizarlo en la vista.

```
{data.direccion.map((dir) => (
<td>{dir.calle}</td>
))}
```

esto me devuelve tanto la calle 1 como la calle 2. ¿como puedo obtener solo la calle 2?
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, es que no se como hacerlo he probado indexOf() y otras cosas y no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr esto puedes hacer una validación antes de mostrar el contenido utilizando el operador lógico AND (&&), de tal forma que si no se cumple la condición no se mostrara nada.

```
{data.direccion.map((dir) => (
    dir.id == 2 &&
    <td>{dir.calle}</td>
 ))}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos me funciona tambien tu solución. Llega un punto que te lias tanto que no sabes ni lo que estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 2):

segun leo lo que estas haciendo actualmente en tu codigo con la funcion "map" es recorrer el arreglo, es por ello que te lanza los dos resultados. Y lo que necesitas es buscar una propiedad en concreto dentro de tu arreglo, en este caso es mucho mas conveniente utlizar la funcion "find"

[image: pantallazo de runJs]

fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, que simple parece y no entiendo como no me salía.